# Java static final String has unexpected contents

Tags: java, static, final

I'm seeing some very strange behavior in a java program. The failure is not reproducible, so all I have to go on is the original logs.

The class looks something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static final String MY_CONSTANT_STRING = "This should never change";

    public boolean checkEndsWithCS(String inString) {
        return inString.endsWith(MY_CONSTANT_STRING);
    }

    public String getString() {
        return "Some text '" + MY_CONSTANT_STRING + "' some more text";
    }
}
```

In the logs, I see a case where getString returns "Some text '' some more text" and checkEndsWithCS("These are not the chars you're looking for.") returns true.

I can only conclude that MY_CONSTANT_STRING is "" in this case.

No other class extends MyClass, so it's not getting overridden in a higher level class.

I don't see any sign of an out of memory condition in the log, which would seem like the most likely cause.

It's static final, so the reference shouldn't change. Strings are immutable, so the string shouldn't change.

Questions:

1. When do these execute? I set a breakpoint in eclipse, and it never gets hit.
2. Is there any possible way for an immutable string in a static final reference to change?
3. Is there any possible way for the string not to get assigned in the first place?
4. Is there any way the memory containing the string or reference could be getting "clobbered" by some other object or process?
5. Any other subtle gotchas where I'm just not thinking about this the right way?

If the collective experience here can't break this loose, then I'll just take it as a sign that my data are faulty and examine it from that angle.

Comment: Can you show the code accessing `MyClass.MY_CONSTANT_STRING`?

Comment: I am not sure, but referencing it in static initialization block *could* be a problem.

Comment: @jlordo Yes I think you're right.

Comment: @tbroberg Usually it's something silly, like you have another constant named MY_CONSTANT_STRING different from MyClass.MY_CONSTANT_STRING and  you are mixing them up in your code. Worth double checking IMO

Comment: I am a bit stuck on the comment about breakpoint, which line did you try to set a breakpoint on? Did you try to check any other line in your MyClass instance?

Comment: If you compile a class when the String was "" and recompile the `MyClass` but not the class which uses it, you many not see the change.  This is because the compiler will in line constants such as String.

Comment: @jlordo updated to include methods that access the string and the description updated to use the methods.

Comment: @posdef, I put a breakpoint on the assignment of MY_CONSTANT_STRING which never gets triggered. There was a subsequent static final int assignment which also did not respond to a breakpoint.

Comment: @tbroberg: Do you have any static imports? Have you tried cleaning your project? Does a breakpoint at `getString()` trigger? If yes, you can check the contents of `MY_CONSTANT_STRING` there. If no, you're not calling that method.

Comment: Have you tried to check the runtime value of different variables including MY_CONSTANT_STRING, using a debugger. If not, it is worth trying that so that you can catch some gotcha, you may not be otherwise able to see. Also if you cant use the debugger, can you Syso the variable before doing operation on them.

Comment: So what? Where in this code is it guaranteed that the value of `inString` is exactly what is returned by `getString()`?

Not a real question.

Comment: It was, in fact, something silly. Two unrelated processes caused the two symptoms. The real problem was poor assumptions about the timing of messages in a queue between two threads. Your comments helped point me away from modification of the static final string. Thanks to all!

Comment: Since the real problem was totally unrelated, the best thing to do is to close this question.

Comment: @StephenC I was thinking that too, but the answers address the question so darned well. I don't know that my actual problem is relevant to value of the question and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use Java reflection to change the values of `final` fields, or mess around with the private fields of a `String` object.

It is also possible for native code (e.g. `native` methods) to overwrite memory, and that could potentially lead to some String object's length *changing* to zero.

If something in your code-base is doing this kind of stuff, it is going to be difficult to identify the culprit.  And you shouldn't entirely overlook possibilities like:

- some third party library doing it,
- some non-trusted code doing it (if you are running non-trusted code without a sandbox),
- something exploiting a known security flaw ... 'cos you haven't been keeping up to date with your patching,
- something (or someone) interfering with the log file.

Or you might not be running code that matches the source code that you are looking at.

---

> 1) When do these execute? I set a breakpoint in eclipse, and it never gets hit.  I put a breakpoint on the assignment of MY_CONSTANT_STRING ...

That code gets executed as part of the static initialization of the class.  Maybe it was executed before you set the breakpoint.  Or maybe there is a bug in the debugger.

> 2) Is there any possible way for an immutable string in a static final reference to change?

Yes.  See above.

> 3) Is there any possible way for the string not to get assigned in the first place?

Given just your code as written here, No.  However, if you have a cycle in the static initialization graph, it is possible to see the value of `MY_CONSTANT_STRING` before it has been assigned.  However, that value will be `null` ... not an empty string.

> 4) Is there any way the memory containing the string or reference could be getting "clobbered" by some other object or process?

Yes.  See above.

> 5) Any other subtle gotchas where I'm just not thinking about this the right way?

Possibly.  I can't read your mind from this distance :-)

Answer (score 2):

Almost surely, either:

1. This is not the actual code you're executing, and your real code does something meaningfully different which explains the difference. Ask your IDE to take you to the declaration of this constant where it is used. It may not be what you think.
2. This is your source code, but the compiled code is not up to date. It looks like you're executing / not executing code that you're not / are
3. You are not actually calling this class

`static` assignments and initializers happen when the class is initialized, before any methods of the class are called or instances created. This is guaranteed. `String` is immutable, and `final` references do not change after assignment. You can't override fields, ever, and can't override anything static, ever. (Though you can hide them for sure.)

The only other value you could possibly observe for this field is `null`, which would happen if it is `final` but you reference it in a `static` block before it is assigned -- which is hard to do, can only happen in a sort of circular initialization scenario.

Barring a JVM bug -- and, this is not utterly impossible -- no a reference can't be corrupted by any action of Java code.